# Upload file using java MultipartEntityBuilder throws Content too long. What's an alternative?

Tags: java, rest, httpclient

I'm trying to make a little utility that will synchronise data between two servers. Most of the calls there are REST calls with JSON, so I decided to use Apache HttpClient for this. 
There is however a section where I need to upload a file. I'm trying to do this using the mutipart form data with the MutipartEntityBuilder but I encounter a Content too long problem. (I tried to gzip the contents of the file too, but I'm still going over the limit).

Here's my java code:

```
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(baseUrl+URL);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        //create upload file params
        builder.addTextBody("scanName", "Test upload");
        builder.addBinaryBody("myfile", f);

        HttpEntity params= builder.build();

        request.setEntity(params);

        request.addHeader("content-type","multipart/form-data");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Are there better atlernatives that I should be using for the file upload part? I'm also going to download the files from one of the server. Will I hit a similar issue when try to handle those responses?

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I`m not quite sure, but maybe problem in servers limitations? I mean that one of servers (or both) have limitations for file size and you need to change this settings. For example, in Spring you need to set follow settings:  spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize for file/request sizes and spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold for size of parts.

Comment: @ZhenyaM it's unlikely. The server supports up to 200 MB files and I can do the same upload from the swagger documentation page.

Comment: Fine, could you post stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to use your code and send some file with size something about 33MB and it was successful. So, I think your problem one of the follows:

1. Created http client has limitations for request size - in this case you need to change properties of client or use another client;
2. In some peace of code you call `HttpEntity.getContent()` method. For multipart request for this method exists limitations - 25kB. For this case you need to use `writeTo(OutputStream)` instead of `getContent()`

In comments you told about swagger, but I don't understand what does it mean. If you use swagger generated api, that problems maybe occurred at their code and you need to fix generation logic (or something like this - I never used swagger)

I hope my answer will help you

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. I was trying to use getContent() on the parameters built with HttpEntity.  It turns out that my problem was caused by not setting a boundary on the request rather than the content being too long. I was chasing a red herring here.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code example that I used to solve the issue of the "Content too long exception"

```
public CloseableHttpResponse sendPostRequestWithFile(URI url, Map<String, String> headersMap, String filePath) throws IOException {
    var boundary = generateBoundary();
    var builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setBoundary(boundary);

    HttpEntity entity = builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
            .addBinaryBody("attachment", new File(filePath), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, filePath).build();

    var request = new HttpPost(url);
    setReuqestHeaders(request, headersMap);
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    entity.writeTo(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();

    HttpEntity httpEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(outputStream.toByteArray());
    request.setEntity(httpEntity);
    return executeRequest(request);
}
```